# how to change the status bar color in flutter web app?

Tags: flutter

I am designing a simple web app and the use case requires the status bar color to change as soon as the browser opens.

I tried using the below mentioned code but it seems to work only on android. I want it to work in flutter web. Any solutions or ideas would be appreciated.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(const SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Color(0xffff3838),
  ));
  configureApp();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

But the results come as :

[image]

I want to change this blue color to orange.

Comment: Add `theme_color ` (or change it) in the manifest file to desired color.

Comment: Tried that in ```manifest.json``` but its not changing at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71474183), `manifest.json` didn't work for me but the `index.html` worked perfectly.

For examples:

```
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)" content="#FFFFFF">
<meta name="theme-color" media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)"  content="#000000">
```

For me:

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#FFFFFF">
```

Note that opacity won't work in this case, solid color only. Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).